# how to get out string oracle regex

Tags: regex, oracle

I have the following string my trying get out the 1111111 and 33333333333 with out the | 
character

```
SELECT regexp_substr('7|1111111|2222222|33333333333|0||20140515|||false|0|0|0|0|0|','*[|]*[|][0-9]*')FROM dual
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) may be a bit simpler;

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('7|1111111|2222222|33333333333|0||20140515|||false|0|0|0|0|0|', 
                      '^([^|]*[|]){1}([^|]*).*$', '\2') FROM dual;

> 1111111

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('7|1111111|2222222|33333333333|0||20140515|||false|0|0|0|0|0|', 
                      '^([^|]*[|]){3}([^|]*).*$', '\2') FROM dual;

> 33333333333
```

You can choose column by choosing how many pipes to skip in the `{1}` part.

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/29879).

A short explanation of the regexp;

```
([^|]+[|]){3}    -- Matches 3 groups of {optional characters}{pipe}
(\d*)            -- Matches the next digit group (the one we want)
.*               -- Matches the rest of the expression
```

What we want is the second paranthesized group, that is, we replace the whole string by the back reference `\2`.

Comment: Didn't work for generic field: No support for empty fields and non-digit values. E.g. try to extract `20140515` or `false` from example string. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/29863)

Comment: @ThinkJet Thanks, I generalized the regex a little to cover your test cases (now included in the SQLfiddle in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Because "`|`" separators always present it's simpler to extract fields with simple substring function rather than using regular expressions.
Just find positions of corresponding separators in source string and extract content between them:

```
with test_data as (
  select 
    '7|1111111|2222222|33333333333|0||20140515|||false|0|0|0|0|0|ABC' as s,
    8 as field_number  -- test 1, 3, 8, 10 and 16
  from dual   
)  
select 
  field_number,
  substr(
    s, 
    decode( field_number, 
      1,1, 
      instr(s,'|',1,field_number - 1) + 1
    ),
    (
      decode( instr(s,'|',1,field_number), 
        0, length(s)+ 1, 
        instr(s,'|',1,field_number)
      )
      - 
      decode( field_number, 
        1, 1, 
        instr(s,'|',1,field_number - 1) + 1
      )
    ) 
  ) as field_value
from 
  test_data
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/29857)

This variant works with empty fields, non-numeric fields and so on.

Possible simplification with appending additional separators to the start and the end of the string:

```
with test_data as (
  select 
    ( 
      '|' ||
      '7|1111111|2222222|33333333333|0||20140515|||false|0|0|0|0|0|ABC' ||
      '|' 
    ) as s, -- additional separators appended before and after original string
    10 as field_number  -- test 1, 3, 8, 10 and 16
  from dual   
)  
select 
  field_number,
  substr(
    s,
    instr(s, '|', 1, field_number) + 1,
    (
      instr(s, '|', 1, field_number + 1)
      -
      (instr(s, '|', 1, field_number) + 1)
    )  
  ) as field_value
from 
  test_data
;
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/29862)